# How to get a win32 handle of an open file in python?

Tags: python, winapi

I'm sure this is documented somewhere but i can't find it...

My code is getting a python object from another library (that i can't modify), and i need to call some win32 api functions on it.

Python returns something that isn't the os-level handle from file.fileno(), my guess is that it gives MSVCRT's fileno.

```
>>> ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateFileA('test',0x80000000L,1,None,3,0,0)
1948 # <- HANDLE

>>> file('test','r').fileno()
4 # <- not a HANDLE
```

How do i convert it into a real win32 handle?

Comment: This seems like a hackish approach to do things. I suggest using the CreateFile approach as you have full control on what parameters are passed to CreateFile, and its generally the right way to get a handle. You can do it with win32file aswell (instead of ctypes).

Comment: It might be hackish, but i can't do CreateFile() myself because i get a python file object from code not under my control.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
>>> msvcrt.get_osfhandle(a.fileno())
1956 # valid HANDLE
```

This is actually documented on http://docs.python.org/library/msvcrt.html , no idea how i missed it.

Answer (score 4):

`win32file._get_osfhandle` from the `PyWin32` library will return what you want.
`win32file._get_osfhandle(a.fileno())` returns the same thing as `msvcrt.get_osfhandle(a.fileno())` in my testing.